# Replacing list element within list element with a string

Tags: python, list, ascii, nested-lists

So I am trying to create a grid that can have it's individual "grid squares" replaced by any given symbol. The grid works fine but it is made of lists within lists.

Here's the code

```
size = 49
feild = []
for i in range(size):
    feild.append([])
for i in range(size):
    feild[i].append("#")
feild[4][4] = "@" #This is one of the methods of replacing that I have tried
for i in range(size):
    p_feild = str(feild)
    p_feild2 = p_feild.replace("[", "")
    p_feild3 = p_feild2.replace("]", "")
    p_feild4 = p_feild3.replace(",", "")
    p_feild5 = p_feild4.replace("'", "")
    print(p_feild5)
```

As you can see that is one way that I have tried to replace the elements, I have also tried:

```
feild[4[4]] = "@"
```

and

```
feild[4] = "@"
```

The first one replaces all "#" 4 elements in from the left with "@"
The second one gives the following error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make a grid of `#` with row 3, column 3 replaced with `@`:

```
>>> size = 5
>>> c = '#'
>>> g = [size*[c] for i in range(size)]
>>> g[3][3] = '@'
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in g))
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
# # # @ #
# # # # #
```

Comment: If I do this I will get a grid entirely of "@", I just want to replace one element

Comment: @ayNONE I updated the answer to allow you to change individually any row-column.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're looking for this :-

```
size = 49
feild = []
for i in range(size):
    feild.append([])
for i in range(size):
    map(feild[i].append, ["#" for _ in xrange(size)])
i = 4
feild[i][0] = "@"
```

Comment: But wouldn't create multiple "@". I just want to replace specific grid squares.

Comment: Not an issue, which ever grid square you want to replace, just specify its row index as i in feild[i][0]

Comment: This replaces the entire grid if I leave it as i. If I change i it does a whole row.

Comment: I think, it'll change specific element in your grid. Your grid is at present 49 * 1. So, to change any element you'll have to set grid[<rowNo>][0] = <val>

Comment: I have changed code. Now your grid will become of size 49 * 49.

Comment: Now clarify that whether you want to replace entire row or specific cell in grid ?